# How to create IPSEC association and Policies in C programming

Tags: c, ipsec

I am building a client-server programming in c with communication between then over `ESP/IPSEC`.

Server on every new client connection, generate a random/unique CK/IK which was transmitted to client by some secure mechanism. I have create association and policies for different client in SPD and SAD of kernel using the `PF_KEY` socket programming. But this mechanism has some problem,
it start getting slow as soon as `80,000` association is created and my requirement is for `1000,000` association for load testing.

I have come to know that `PF_KEY` socket mechanism is old and outdated and insecure. This mechanism is `KLIPS`. There are two mechanism, `KLIPS` and `NETKEY`.

How to create association of `IPSEC` through `NETKEY` mechanism in c programming in user space?

Comment: If you don't want to reinvent the wheel and if opensource ipsec ike manangement tools works for you then please try [1]strongswan and [2]libreswan, you can also try openswan but they don't have much active development.
[1]https://www.strongswan.org/
[2] https://libreswan.org/
If you want you own implementation then you could also use their (libreswan and strongswan) code as reference for your implementation.
latest version of Strongswan only support Netkey and Libreswan also has Netkey as default

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend that you use **[Wireguard over Ipsec](https://www.wireguard.com/performance/)**, it is way better, approved by Linus Torvald and developed by very talented security researcher.

Sorry if it is slightly offtopic but you look like you are still exploring. [Ipsec](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPsec) is from the 1990s, and it indeed brought a lot along the years, but Wireguard was started from scratch just few years ago with the merit of having a very short (and easily auditable) code, that was also optimized with the latest technologic breakthroughs.

You can find this beautiful project, its mirror, on [Github](https://github.com/WireGuard/wireguard-linux), and it is mainly coded in C (as for the original project).

NB: Wireguard encrypt traffic through https (port 443), so it also allow users to go through all the kind of great firewalls built by dictatorships 2.0 around the world, as everyone needs to access https.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the DaVICI plugin of StrongSwan.
https://github.com/strongswan/davici